# Finding device (manufacturer) details with its device type for the MAC address of a laptop/phone/iPad?

Tags: mac, mac-address, device-mapper

Is there way to find the Device (Or Device manufacturer) details with the MAC address of that device?

I need this, to check whether the connected MACs are Laptop (PC)/Mobile Phones/Tablet (iPads).

Comment: First 6 hex digits of MAC allows to identify the vendor in more than half of cases. Search for some "MAC to vendor" online service (or downloadable table) and use it.

Comment: Yes @Akina thanks. I tried some online links to find the vendor name. I stuck with finding the device type.

Comment: I have never seen that the vendor publishes the MAC-DeviceType table...

Comment: You can only guess. There's no any public standard for this.